# How can I call a module in a Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, module

Say I have a data file that I want to process; I want to take the maximum value of each of the column and append it to the end of each line.

#### INPUT:

```
T1 T2 T3
35.82 34.67 31.68
32.20 34.52 33.59
37.41 38.64 37.56
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
T1 T2 T3
35.82 34.67 31.68 35.82
32.20 34.52 33.59 34.52
37.41 38.64 37.56 38.64
```

I'm trying to implement this as a one-liner. So far, this is what I've come up with, although it complains that  `&main::max` is undefined:

```
perl -MList::Util -ani.bak -e "print qq(@F).q( ).max(@F).qq(\n)" file1.txt
```

It seems that I haven't loaded the `List::Util` module. What's wrong? And is the header column an issue?

<strike>[perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) doesn't have a decent example on how to do this</strike> (*actually it does, my documentation was a little hard to read*).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You loaded `List::Util`, but the module doesn't export symbols by default. Skip the header line by checking whether `$.` is 1.

```
$ perl -MList::Util=max -ape 's/$/" " . max(@F)/e unless $.==1' input 
T1 T2 T3
35.82 34.67 31.68 35.82
32.20 34.52 33.59 34.52
37.41 38.64 37.56 38.64
```

The [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-m*%5b*-*%5d_module_) documentation explains:

> A little builtin syntactic sugar means you can also say **-mmodule=foo,bar** or **-Mmodule=foo,bar** as a shortcut for `-Mmodule qw(foo bar)`. This avoids the need to use quotes when importing symbols. The actual code generated by **-Mmodule=foo,bar** is `use module split(/,/,q{foo,bar})`. Note that the `=` form removes the distinction between **-m** and **-M**.

Comment: Sweet. The `s///e` trick is a nice little takeaway. Just need to make sure it works for inline editing.

Comment: It does. I modified it to include a new header as well: `perl -i.bak -MList::Util=max -ape 's/$/" " .($.===1 ? "TMAX" : max(@F))/e' input`

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -M"List::Util 'max'" -ani.bak -e "print qq(@F).q( ).max(@F).qq(\n)" file1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

List::Util was loaded, but it doesn't export the `max` function by default:

```
perl -MList::Util -ani.bak -e "print qq(@F).q( ).List::Util::max(@F).qq(\n)" file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

if Perl is not a must, here's an awk one-liner

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>t){t=$i};print $0,t;t=0}' file
35.82 34.67 31.68 35.82
32.20 34.52 33.59 34.52
37.41 38.64 37.56 38.64
```